# Deploy failed on Visual Studio 17 Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

After the last update of Visual Studio Community (15.6.2) I was unable to deploy or debug projects.

I can Build the project, but when i deploy, the output appears as follows.

[image: Deploy Error]

I already changed JDK, for versions 1.8.161 and 1.8.131, it did not work. I checked versions of the SDK I was using, so I installed API 22 and API 25, both of which I use in my project.

None of this working, I restored my Visual studio, it also did not work.

Looking for a solution, I deleted the android-sdk folder and uninstalled Visual Studio completely.

After installation, to my surprise, it did not work again.
Then I accessed Tools> Options> Xamarin and checked that there was no NDK installed. As a possible alternative I even installed it.

I think my options have run out, I created a project from the beginning with the name XamarinNotRun without even a change and even then I can not deploy.

Some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/troubleshooting/questions/jdk9-errors#known-issues-with-jdk-9

Specifically JDK 9 is on your `PATH` somehow and thus `apksigner.bat` throws an error as it's not compatible with JDK 9.

The easiest remedy is to uninstall JDK 9 in any form and remove it from your path in your environment variables. You can double check that you did this correctly by typing the following on a command line:

`java -version`

In which it results in displaying information about JDK 8 instead.